# .NET DLL that references older .NET assemblies

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I am referencing some .NET DLLs in my .NET 3.5 project.  Those DLLs have references to .NET 2.0 assemblies (like System.Data, etc.).  I can not recompile those DLLs.  I would like to install only .NET 3.5 and not have to install .NET 2.0.  Will those DLLs work just fine?  If not, is there anything I can do to have them use the 3.5 assemblies instead of the 2.0 assemblies they were compiled against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET v2.0.50727 is required for .NET v3.0 and v3.5.

All v3.x added is Windows Communication Foundation, Windos Workflow Foundation and Windows Presentation Foundation (at the runtime level)

I believe the compiler for the v3.x SDK offers the language extensions for the v3.x framework.
The compiler is able to handle v2 and v3 compiles.

You can run v2 code unmodified on v2.x and greater .NET frameworks, but you cannot run v3.x .NET code ontop of the v2 framework only.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 1.1 and .NET 2.0 are separate.

However, .NET 3.5 is backwards compatible with .NET 3.0 and .NET 2.0. So, you're fine if your assemblies are 2.0 assemblies.

Comment: so are you saying that all .NET 2.0 assemblies are installed for .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

.NET 3.x is based off of .NET 2.0.